# Find SDE satisfied by transformation of solution to a different SDE

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose that $X_t$ satisfies $dX_t = Y_t dt + Y_t dW_t$, where $dY_t = Y_t dW_t$. What can we say about the SDE that $\ln{(X_t)} + \frac{t}{2}$ solves? I'm not sure how to use the SDE that $X_t$ solves to find the SDE that $\ln{(X_t)} + \frac{t}{2}$ solves. In general, is there a way to find the SDE that the transformation of the process solves?

I know that $dY_t = Y_t dW_t$ is a GBM with no drift, so that means $Y_t = Y_0 e^{-\frac{1}{2}t + W_t}$. Then we have $dX_t = Y_0 e^{-\frac{1}{2}t + W_t} (dt + dW_t)$. Is there any easy way to solve this? I'm not sure how to efficiently apply Ito's lemma in this case. Once a solution to $X_t$ is found, would we then apply that transformation and find the SDE it solves? Am I overcomplicating things? I'm not sure if there is a better way, and I'm still stuck trying to solve for $X_t$. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $Z_t=\frac{t}{2}+\ln{(X_t)}$ and denote quadratic variation by $\langle\cdot\rangle$.  By Ito, $$dZ_t=d\left(\frac{t}{2}+\ln{(X_t)}\right)=\frac{dt}{2}+\frac{dX_t}{X_t}-\frac{\langle X_t\rangle}{X_t^2}\,dW_t$$  Now note that \begin{gather*}
X_t=e^{Z_t-\frac{t}{2}} \\
dX_t=Y_t(dt+dW_t) \\
\langle X_t\rangle=Y_t
\end{gather*}  Thus \begin{align*}
dZ_t&=\frac{dt}{2}+Y_te^{\frac{1}{2}t-Z_t}(dt+dW_t)-Y_te^{t-2Z_t}\,dW_t \\
&=\left(\frac{1}{2}+Y_te^{\frac{1}{2}t-Z_t}\right)dt+Y_te^{\frac{1}{2}t-Z_t}\left(1-e^{\frac{1}{2}t-Z_t}\right)\,dW_t
\end{align*}

You've already noticed that $Y_t=Y_0e^{W_t-\frac{t}{2}}$, so we can substitute that to get a slightly nicer answer: $$dZ_t=\left(\frac{1}{2}+Y_0e^{W_t-Z_t}\right)dt+e^{W_t-Z_t}\left(1-e^{\frac{1}{2}t-Z_t}\right)\,dW_t$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Is there now a way to solve this SDE given that $Y_t = Y_0 e^{-\frac{1}{2}t + W_t}$?

Comment: @cosmicflair: No, I don't see a way.  Not every SDE has an expressible solution.  I did miss that substituting $Y_t$ gives a nicer final result, though, so I edited that into my answer.

Comment: why do you say is $\langle X \rangle_t = Y_t$? Isn't it $\langle X \rangle_t = \int_0^t Y_s^2 ds$?

Comment: @Sebastian: No, that's (roughly) the $L^2$ norm.  The [quadratic variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation) is $\sup_{\{t_j\}_j\vdash[0,t]}{\sum_j{(X_{t_{j+1}}-X_{t_j})^2}}$.

Comment: @JacobManaker: In your last comment, you provided the definition of quadratic variation which by the way you don't use in your answer. There is also a characterization that says that the quadratic variation process of the process $X$ is the unique process such that $X^2 - \langle X \rangle$ is a martingale. Using this characterization and the Ito isometry is easy to show that $\langle X \rangle_t = \int_0^t Y_s^2ds.$

Comment: @JacobManaker: you can see it here also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation#It%C3%B4_processes or any book in the subject